# Sum two properties of the same node in Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I can sum a property of all the node given from a cypher query. But ¿is it posible to sum two properties of the same node?

Example:
MATCH (n: `Node`) WITH n.a + n.b as sum RETURN sum

**UPDATE:** Resolve in other comments, but if you want to get a sum of multiple properties of all nodes you can do:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
WITH sum(n.a + n.b) AS sum
RETURN sum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In your example you could just do

```
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n.a + n.b AS sum
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/dqq2cx

Comment: Since he mentions summing a (single) property of all nodes, do you think he might be looking to `sum()` the sum of `n.a + n.b` for all nodes?  (I.e., http://console.neo4j.org/r/yr1oqx)

Comment: Oh, maybe. I'm not sure.

Comment: I was looking for the sum of two properties of a single node, but we can resolve that problem for future solutions.